# Remove inner boundaries in merged vector layers

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, vector-layer, watershed, catchment-area

I am using QGIS and the GRASS plugin for a watershed analysis where I would like to merge three small natural catchments into a larger one.
I used the 'Merge Vector Layers' function (under the 'Vector' menu and 'Data management tools') to merge all vector layers into one single vector layer (shown in yellow, in the uploaded screenshot).
However the inner catchment boundaries remain.

Is there any simple way to remove them?

[image]

Comment: The tool you are looking for is `Dissolve`. It's in the "Vector->Geometry tools" menu.

Comment: @Micha Worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: @Micha would be good to post as an answer.

Comment: A bit short for posting as an answer...